# Calling typeof operator in jQuery Template data tags?

Tags: jquery-templates

Is it possible to call `typeof(x)` within a data rendering template tag?

```
${typeof(x)}
```

[Obligatory example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/Bxwmc/)

#### Workaround

I can alias the `typeof` operator as a custom template function and it works fine, but I would like to avoid that extra level of redirection if I can.

```
// calling JavaScript
$("#reflectTemplate").tmpl(data, {
    getType: function(itemToCheck) {
        return typeof(itemToCheck);
    }
}).appendTo(".results");

<!--template tag-->
${$item.getType(prop)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to force the result to be a string. One or both of these should work in most browsers:

```
${String(typeof(prop))}
${typeof(prop)+''}
```